# Why does nosetests wait for two seconds before executing?

Tags: python, nose

When I run `nosetests` in a project, it always takes at least 2 seconds to execute, even if there are no tests, or the tests are trivial (e.g. `assert_equal(1,1)`)

Why is nosetests so slow?

2 seconds may not seem long, but it makes really fast-twitch development cycles impossible.

This has bugged me for a long time---would love to implement an elegant workaround, if possible.

EDIT: Added code to reproduce.

Here's `test_nose_stuff.py`:

```
from nose.tools import assert_equal, assert_dict_equal

def test_stuff():
    pass
```

From a directory containing only that one file:

```
$ time nosetests
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK

real    0m1.103s
user    0m0.585s
sys     0m0.237s
```

In repeated trials, real execution times vary from .5 to 1.2 seconds.

I'm running python 2.7.13, installed via conda, nosetests version 1.3.7.

Comment: **It doesn't.**  You'll have to post the steps to recreate your issue.

Answer (score 4):

I decided to profile it, `nose` on startup spends most of its time initializing `pkg_resources` (the plugin framework from `setuptools`)

My profiling script looks essentially like this:

```
python -m cProfile -o stats.pstats $(which nosetests)
gprof2dot.py --skew=.1 -wn3 -f pstats stats.pstats | dot -Tsvg -o stats.svg
```

The `gprof2dot.py` I'm using is a fork of the actual project so the svgs aren't as broken: https://github.com/Yelp/gprof2dot

https://i.fluffy.cc/6KxlHKw44TSbdn2WGkWtskBrfd4RdpBK.svg

If you have many packages installed, `pkg_resources` takes a long time to initialize.

With this minimal pip freeze:

```
$ pip freeze
nose==1.3.7
wheel==0.24.0
$ time nosetests
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK

real    0m0.166s
user    0m0.120s
sys 0m0.012s
```

With more packages installed:

```
$ pip freeze | wc -l
430
$ time nosetests
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK

real    0m0.501s
user    0m0.360s
sys 0m0.076s
```

This time increases *dramatically*

Comment: Super helpful. Follow up: is it possible suppress use of pkg_resources in nose? I hate that deadweight time in my testing cycle.

Comment: It's initialized at the module scope: https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/7c26ad1e6b7d308cafa328ad34736d34028c122a/nose/plugins/manager.py#L418  You could `pip uninstall setuptools`, but that's probably ill advised :)